# How to send a bitmap using serversocket

Tags: java, android, arrays, bitmap, serversocket

I am making a multiplayer drawing application for android and I need to send the drawings that every user made to one player. I am using a server socket for this.

First thing I do is convert the Bitmap to a byte array, so I can send it to the Host with host.write(byteArray);

```
        Bitmap bitmapImage = drawView.getBitmap();
        byte[] byteArray = getByteArray(bitmapImage);
        byteArrayLength = byteArray.length;

        MainWifiActivity.SendReceive host = MainWifiActivity.sendReceiveHost;
        if (host != null) {
            host.write(byteArray);
        }
```

The following code is my SendReceive class, which listenes to the inputStream and then starts a Handler, that is supposed to save the Bitmap to Internal Storage

```
    public class SendReceive extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private OutputStream outputStream;

    public SendReceive(Socket s) {
        socket = s;
        try {
            inputStream = s.getInputStream();
            outputStream = s.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
    @Override
    public void run() {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;
        int filesize;

        while (socket != null) {
            try {
                filesize = DrawingActivity.byteArrayLength;
                if(buffer.length != filesize && filesize > 0){
                    buffer = new byte[filesize];
                }
                bytes = inputStream.read(buffer,0 ,buffer.length);

                if (bytes > 0) {
                        Message mesg = handler.obtainMessage(IMAGE_MSG, bytes, -1, buffer);
                        mesg.sendToTarget();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

And the Handler:

```
    Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch (msg.what) {
            case IMAGE_MSG:
                byte[] byteArray = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                saveBitmapToInternalStorage(bitmap);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

In the saveBitmapToInternalStorage Method I get a java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

```
    private void saveBitmapToInternalStorage(Bitmap bmp) {
    File directory = getApplicationContext().getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File myPath = new File(directory, UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("HELLO", "MY ERROR: " + e);
    } finally {
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I know that BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray returns the decoded bitmap, or null if the image could not be decoded.

But why could it not be decoded?

Answer (score 0):

I think this piece is wrong

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
```

It should be

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
    try {
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
```

Comment: It gives me "Unhandled exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException" if I do that

Comment: If the directory doesn't exist create it using directory.mkdirs() as you can see the compiler is complaining the file is not found.

Comment: I use getApplicationContext().getDir() and on the android website it sais "Returns A File object for the requested directory. The directory will have been created if it does not already exist." Also, if i try to save the bitmap before sending it to the host (on the phone where the drawing was created) it does save into the right directory, so it must be something to do with the data sending part.

Comment: When you create myPath you need to check if it exists and create it if it doesn't. There are multiple examples on the web. FileNotFound exception is thrown if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I don´t get a FileNotFoundException when I run the code, it sais "Unhadled exception" because in your code FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath); is not in a try catch, and it throws this error before i even run the code, so it won´t even compile